# justify-content: space-between elements are not at the edges

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the problem, that the items do not use the full `width`. In the codepen they use the space better than in my original code, but they also dont use the full `width` and I really dont know why.

The differenze between `space-between` and `space-around` are minimal which they shouldnt be. (not tested in this codepen)

http://codepen.io/notyetnamed/pen/KdMqJV

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <ul class="cf">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <ul class="cf">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>Lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1256px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-between;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  &:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
  }

  &:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
.wrapper ul li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 186px;
  width: 15.30%;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding: 0;` and removing the `clear fix` (which I overlooked...) solved it.

Thanks to all!

Comment: The padding itself fixes the issue completely in the code above. There is no mention of clear fix anywhere in your code (ps: I am not the one voting you down either)

Comment: Your right. I forgot it in the code abouve, I´ll add it but in the Codepen the clearfix is on the ul.

Comment: I am a bit disappointed to see how you're abusing the system. From all questions you have asked on Stackoverflow, you have accepted not one answer.

Instead, you proceed to answer your own question and mark it as the answer two days later. In this case, your answer is not even correct as the `cf` or clearfix added to your `ul` has absolutely no effect on the horizontal spacing.

/rant

Comment: Than please recheck the code. My main problem was the cf. The point I answer my own question is, because I found the solution on my own with some help of the community here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `box-sizing` property to `border-box` to adjust how the sizes are calculated.

For ease of use, I added it to all elements, but for optimisations I highly suggest you only add it to the elements you need it to be added to. As you should do with all CSS anyway.

As for your issue with the width, perhaps removing `width: 15.30%;` would solve that, as exemplified below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1256px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper ul {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-between;
  -ms-justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper ul li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <ul class="cf">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <ul class="cf">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/180/180/" alt="">
          <h3>Lorem</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: The green surrounded box is still far far away from the edge of the red box.

Comment: Either you're using a very old browser, or you're not happy with the default behaviour of your current browser. Adding `padding: 0;` to `.wrapper ul` would solve your issue and push the content 40 pixels left, to where you probably expect them to be. (edit: updated pen)

Comment: If the default styles a browser applies to elements is an issue for you (like it is for many others), you can google for `css reset` or use `normalize.css`, which is my personal favourite, but they're really all the same: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Your code should go in your answer, not on 3rd party sites like Codepen or  JSfiddle. And on a personal note, please don't link to w3schools. They are a terrible resource. If you want to link to something, link to MDN.

Comment: I did not add the code to the answer, as the code was present in the question, so I figured directions to edit it (and with a pen as example) would be enough. Thanks for adding it as a snippet, though! I do agree with w3schools, but in this specific case they did a pretty good job

Answer (score 0):

You should start by setting the margin and padding to zero at top level.
ul elements come with default padding.
Just add this to wrapper ul:

```
.wrapper ul {
 padding: 0;
...
```

or even better, start your css with

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You will get rid of any unwanted default paddings and margins.

Comment: Please explain the down votes. Look at the code, and I'm pretty sure it does what schndr.eu asked for: get rid of the padding that keeps the elements from spreading to the full width.

Comment: schndr.eu can you mark my answer as the correct one since it solved your issue?

Comment: Well, Stephan Bijzitter wrote the same thing earlier and it wasn´t the full solution. I dont understand the down votes as well, but I cant change it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap users, look out for `::before` and `::after` introduced by `.container-fluid`.

Fix:

```
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after {
    content: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48648382