# Why is justify-content: space-between not working?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to implement flexbox but can't get it to work. What am I missing? I have all the flexbox vendor prefixes in place.

```
.main-navigation ul { 
   width:100%; 
   display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
   display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
   display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
   display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  }

.main-navigation ul li {
   justify-content:space-between; 
   width:100px; 
   background:#666; 
   display:block;
 }
```

The goal is to get the left most `li` to go flush with the left of the ul's container and the right most `li` to go flush with the right-hand side of the ul's container. Any help welcome.

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing the vendor prefixes on the space-between rule @alySebastien?

Answer (score 64):

One more thing to keep in mind, additional to the need of adding `justify-content:space-between` to the flex container and not to the elements themselves; Make sure that you don't have empty elements (like an empty `div` or `:after`) inside the container.

In my case turned out a JS adding an empty div as a "clearfix" from the days before flex, when things were done floating elements.

`justify-content:space-between` will justify for all the elements inside the container even those with no content, which can mess up the alignment and wrapping.

Answer (score 32):

The problem is you should set `justify-content: space-between;` on element with `display: flex` property or better say on 'parent', so 'child' elements will be aligned with space between each other.

```
.main-navigation ul { 
  width: 100%; 
  display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
  display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  width: 100px; 
  background: #666; 
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I was missing the vendor prefixes on the space-between rule. :)

Answer (score 16):

Flex properties are divided among two categories: The *flex container* and the *flex items*.

Some properties apply only to the container, other properties apply only to the items.

***The [`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/) property applies only to a flex container.***

In your code, `justify-content` is applied to the items, so it's having no effect.

Re-assign it to the container.

Of course, an element can be both a flex container and item, in which case all properties apply. But that's not the case here. The `li` elements are solely flex items and will ignore container properties.

For a list of flex properties – divided by container and items – see: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)